# Spring Boot accomplish a rollback in an exception not thrown, as is possible in JDBC / JSE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Note below, the in part “catch (UserException e)” is reversed even though it does not propagate the exception. I know supercially, that in Spring Boot the reversal occurs only when there is an exception thrown, as in “catch (Exception e)”. So, how to have something equivalent in Spring Boot?

```
... Transaction in JDBC/JSE
public class UserService {

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void persistsDBFluxoFlowUser(User user, int peso) throws Exception {
        try {
            userDAO = new UserDAO();
            TransactionManager tmDb = new TransactionManager();
            // begin Transaction
            tmDb.createNewConnection(Conexao.DB_X);
            tmDb.addDAO(notaServicoDAO);

            userDAO.save(user);
                
            // More code that can launch  UserException or Exception
                
            tmDb.commit();
        } catch (UserException e) {
            tmDb.rollback();
            log.warn("test");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tmDb.rollback();
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            tmDb.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do this, but it doesn't undo the transaction on “catch (UserException e)”.

```
.... Transaction in Spring 
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class,UserException.class})
    public void persistsDBFluxoFlowUser(User user, int peso)  throws Exception {
        boolean resul;
        try {
                userRepository.save(user);
                
            // More code that can launch  UserException or Exception
                
        } catch (UserException e) {
            log.warn("test");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default every bean is wrapped by Spring - after enable transaction management it add Transaction Adviser ([see section 9.5.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html)).
If you have 2 bean A and B:

```
@Transactional
class A() {
    @Autowire
    private B b;

    public doInTransaction() {
        try {
            b.anotherTransactionalMethod();
            this.someLogic();
        } catch(UserException ex) {
            //ignore exception
        }
    }

    private void someLogic() throws UserException{
        ....
    }
}
```

In such code we can have UserException at:

1. b.anotherTransactionalMethod(); - we call another bean and this call was processed by Transaction Adviser and this adviser must process exception (mark transactional as rollback only). But transaction doesn't break or rollback immediately.
2. this.someLogic(); - it's a local code call, nobody won't process exception and mark transaction.
   So, if you don't delegate work to another bean and don't throw exception (Runtime or mark as rollbackFor)

You can delete try-catch block and transactional will be marked as rollback.

Comment: Thank you so much. This explanation made the issue clear "after enable transaction management it add Transaction Adviser".

Answer (score 0):

You need @EnableTransactionManagement above your Configuration/SpringBoot class. If you need more help, check out this example https://javamondays.com/spring-transactions-explained/